# how to find a text string which may be present in some unknown file in entire filesystem

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, find, grep

I am stuck up with a problem  I have a line 
'something' in some file.
In which file is this line that I have forgotten.
In the entire root file system I would like to find out which file and where is this line.
So how can I go for this.I have used find but when I used find then I knew the name of file in this case I do not know name of file also.
It is  a Ubuntu server 10.04 So what can I do to find out which file has this string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use:

```
find / -xdev | xargs grep "string"
```

That'll give you a list of all of the matched strings along with the actual files they're in.

Answer (score 4):

A simple bruteforce solution would be:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -H 'some string' {} \;
```

(the -H option to gnu grep causes it to return the filename).

However you'd probably benefit from spedning the time writing a smarter script which ignores stuff like binary files, executables (non-script) etc.

Comment: If you do this, make sure you add `-xdev` or otherwise avoid going into /proc and /sys; you can search through those for a **really** long time without finding anything useful.

Comment: Yeah, I really recommend giving the `-I` flag to grep, so that binary files are treated as non-matching.  Really cuts down on the false positives.

Comment: Using `xargs` or `-exec ... +`, if your `find` supports it, will speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

heh well there are a lot of files

maybe if you could narrow it down to some time when you last accessed that file and try

`find / -xdev -type f -atime -X -exec grep -H 'string' {} \;`

where X is number of days from today backwards in which you are sure you accessed the file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like ' grep -iR "text to find" * ' run from the root will do it.